# How is it possible to make phpbb3 take up the whole of the page?

Tags: html, css, height, phpbb3

I have successfully intergrated phpbb3 with my site however now on the login pages there is a white background where the background image should be. How can I make either the background image continue to the end of the page or extend the div to the bottom?

This is my site: [projectstratos.com/forum](http://projectstratos.com/forum)

If you have a small monitor you will have to go to the login page to see what I mean.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your site so we can look at the HTML and CSS?

Comment: http://projectstratos.com/forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles > Your Stylename > Theme > common.css

Here you have 2 choices,

Add to body

```
height: 98%; // Assuming html still has a 101% height
```

Add to #wrap

```
min-height: 1000px; // Your min-height
```

I can provide a better answer if you can share you website with us :)

Comment: I have now and currently my wrap is 100% but this does nothing, I will try the bg repeat

Comment: Have you refreshed your css in the Admin Panel?

Comment: Yes, I have also added a black bacground but for some reason this only works either side of the image and not below it. The white space at the bottom is not in the html tag...

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! This worked, I was putting this into my main style sheet rather than the common one! Oh... maybe not, if you have a look now it cuts it off for some reason! Why would this be?!

Comment: Now, I'm setting min-height as 101% but it cuts off at about 5%!!

Comment: YES, I've got it to work, it wasn't cutting of at 5% it was the padding for the container div.... I just deleted the divs colour and now it works!